# Filter "negative news" out of RSS feed data

Tags: javascript, xml, json, node.js, rss

I am making an application in which I retrieve the data from RSS feeds (this happens each 30 minutes, the previously retrieved RSS data is then overwritten).
However, I only want to show the "good" news. So I want to check the *title* and *description* tags if they contain bad news, in that case I don't want it to be shown. I only want to show the RSS items without bad news.

I have a solution for how I could meet my needs, I was thinking about having a list of negative words. I would then scan the *title* and *description* tags if their values contained any of these words, and if let's say 2 or more words from the negative list have been found in those values, then the item is considered "bad news" and will not be shown. The list would be in JSON like this:

```
"negative":[
    "war","crime","murder","terror", ...]
```

What do you think about this idea? Would there be a better/easier/cleaner solution?

Suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: This would filter out news like: "The war is over"

Comment: Indeed. That's why I was going to only withhold the news items if the amount of negative words contained in the text was >= 2. But I am aware that my solution probably isn't the best

Comment: It is hard what you are trying, indeed. tousends of engineers are working on that since years. It would need the computer to intelligently analyze - understand - the text. Probably you organize some books about AI and settle on existing results of science..

Comment: I understand. But it doesn't have to be perfect though. If sometimes (1 in 50 items or so) a bad news item is shown or a good one is withheld that shouldn't be, it isn't really a big deal. But in the end it should work that (with a slight error margin) only good news is shown. To achieve this, I hoped I wouldn't have to dig as deep as you've mentioned.